# Как долго может существовать побочная цепочка в блокчейне?

Tags: blockchain, блокчейн

Если блоки находятся во второй, не основной цепочке, то как долго транзакции в этих блоках будут существовать? И сможет ли эта цепочка стать основной, если она будет постоянно в сети или она должна быть на локальной ноде, а потом синхронизироваться как главная?

Comment: Транзакции в цепочке могут быть сколь угодно долго. но о них разумеется будут знать только те ноды, которые считают эту цепочку основной. А считать они ее будут основной до тех пор, пока у них не появится связь с нодами, где есть более длинная цепочка (или равная по длине, но с лучшим хешем)

Comment: Основной станет та цепочка которая длиннее. Более короткая цепочка станет побочной. Локальная нода сможет сгенерировать свою более длинную цепочку и затем синхонизировать её как основную только если у неё будет >50% мощности сети.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за ответы. Я что-то не так спросил, за что минус? И еще, мы запросы может слать на свою ноду, а она в автомате синхронизируется с другими?

Comment: @Mike, может ли цепочка считаться главной если хеш лучше, но она короче?

Comment: @EbonyFiftyOne Ну вообще в разных блокчейнах может быть по разному. Как авторы решат. Но думаю в большинстве длина играет решающую роль, ибо можно считать, что для получения более длинной цепочки затрачено больше ресурсов, а с более лучшим хешем вопрос не однозначный, могло просто повезти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Транзакции в цепочке могут быть сколь угодно долго, но о них, разумеется, будут знать только те ноды, которые считают эту цепочку основной. А считать они ее будут основной до тех пор, пока у них не появится связь с нодами, где есть более длинная цепочка (или равная по длине, но с лучшим хешем)

Основной станет та цепочка которая длиннее. Более короткая цепочка станет побочной. Локальная нода сможет сгенерировать свою более длинную цепочку и затем синхронизировать её как основную, только если у неё будет > 50% мощности сети.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, мы общаемся со своей нодой, а она автоматически синхронизируется с другими?